# date conversion to timestamp incorrect, outputs wrong timestamp

Tags: javascript

I have a date that is stored in the database as `"2019-03-03T03:44:00.000Z"`

then in my script I need to convert it to a timestamp...

```
new Date(milestone.flight_time).getTime() / 1000)
```

this created a timestamp of `1551584640` which translates to `3/2/2019, 10:44:00 PM Standard Time)`

The desired result would be for a timestamp equal to the initial ISO string.

Comment: Don't divide by 1000, then convert your result to ISOString, which should be your desired result, see, `let flight_time_stamp = new Date("2019-03-03T03:44:00.000Z").getTime()` `new Date(flight_time_stamp).toISOString()`